# Svelte: using "bind:this" inside "each" block

Tags: svelte

I want to render an array of objects, using an `each` block. I need to be able to remove elements from the array using callbacks from inside the `each` block. Also, for more complex UI-interactions, I need the reference to each component of the `each`-block to be available in the main app.

Here is my approach:

```html
<script>
    let items = [{text: "one"}, {text: "two"}];
    
    function deleteItem(i) {
        items.splice(i, 1);
        items = items;
    }
</script>

{#each items as item, i}
<button bind:this={items[i].ref} on:click={() => deleteItem(i)} >
    {item.text}
</button>   
<p />
{/each}
```

Understandibly, this leads to errors such as `item[i] is undefined`, because when the splicing of `items` is processed, the `bind:this` cannot properly be cleaned up anymore.

I tried to solve this by moving the component-references to a separate array. But no matter what I try, I cannot get the reference-array and the object-array to sync: Whenever `deleteItem()` is processed, I end up with `null`-values inside the `refs`-array. Here is one of my approaches (the `each`-section that prints the `refs`-array should help to show the `null`-values):

```html
<script>
    import {tick } from "svelte";
    let items = [{text: "one", id: 1}, {text: "two", id:2}];
    let refs = [];
    
    async function deleteItem(i) {
        items.splice(i, 1);
        await tick();
        refs.splice(i, 1);
        items = items;
        console.log(refs);
    }
</script>

{#each items as item, i (item.id)}
<button on:click={async () => deleteItem(i)} bind:this={refs[i]}>
    {item.text}
</button>   
<p />
{/each}

{#each refs as ref}
{ref}
<p />
{/each}
```

I tried with and without `tick()`, tried inserting the `tick()` in different places, with and without `async` and with and without using `(item.id)` in the each block. How can I keep the references and the data in sync?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On way to get around this is to have the `refs` array cleaned up before you use it:

```html
<script>
 let items = [...]
 let _refs = []
 $: refs = _refs.filter(Boolean)
</script>

<button bind:this={_refs[i]}></button>
```

With this technique you will still have the `null` values in the original *_refs* array, but the copied version (*refs*) will be clean.

Another way is to bind the element to the item itself, but this might not be desired if you use that data elsewhere as well:

```html
<button bind:this={item.ref}>
```

(note that this will still give errors because the bound element disappears during the slice but is only processed with the assignment, you can get around that by doing the slicing and the assignment in one using a filter statement)

```js
items = items.filter((item, idx) => idx != i)
```

Comment: Thank you - your second approach [works well](https://svelte.dev/repl/6f7916b3486c4a3fabdca84ece345f38?version=3.29.4)!